# Get a list of IDs that have NA by column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get a list of IDs that have NA in each column. For example, if I have:

```
ID  col1  col2
1    2     NA
2    NA    2
3    8     19
4    0     NA
5    NA    4
```

How can I get:

```
col1   col2
2      1
5      4
```

Comment: What if you have unequal values of NA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```r
apply(dat[, -1], 2, \(col) dat$ID[is.na(col)], simplify=F)

# $col1
# [1] 2 5
# 
# $col2
# [1] 1 4
```

I used `simplify=F` so that the result is always a list (and not simplified to a matrix if the numbers of IDs are equal across columns).

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df1 %>%
  reframe(across(-ID, ~ ID[is.na(.x)]))
   col1 col2
1    2    1
2    5    4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** thanks to @onyambu(see comments):

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df[-1], function(x) df$ID[is.na(x)]))
```

**First answer:**
Using `lapply`

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df[-1], function(x) which(is.na(x))))

  col1 col2
1    2    1
2    5    4
```

Comment: You need to take ID into consideration. This works since ID is simply 1:5 and in that order

Comment: Yes but I suppose the ID is equal to row number?!

Comment: What if its not? Thats why it would be better to do `ID[is.na(x)]`